# Why SetVariable inside Foreach loop is not iterating as expected in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, foreach-loop-container

I have my DataFolder on local that contains subfolders. Each subfolder has a date in its name  and can have multiple excel files inside.

[image]

ForEach activity iterating through each subfolder name and loading data from each excel into sql table.

Set variables1 substrings only a data part from subfolder name
Set variable2 simply replacing dots (in a date) with "/"

The question is, why the result sql table only contains 5-31-2023 date? What happened with 06-30-2023?

[image]

SetVariable2 has expression for variable DatePart.

@substring(
item().name
, add(lastIndexOf(item().name, ' '), 1)
, sub(length(item().name), add(lastIndexOf(item().name, ' '),1)))

Next, I am using variable DatePart in a Copy Data activity as a new column.

[image]

Result from sql table:

[image: ![enter image description here]

UPDATE:

Rebuild the pipeline using @RakeshGovindula way.
So why in his way the sequence of executions occurs the wat it should be

[image]

However, in my case the sequence of executions is incorrect order. Everything is the same, even expressions.

[image]

Comment: Can you try having 10 files and FileDateVariable still returns the first one from iteration?

Comment: Just removed extra files. So the first folder has 9 files, second - 10 files. But still same result

Comment: but i was asking which ItemName is default on the FileDateVariable, is it always 5.31.2023? and is this the  first one in the iteration?

Comment: Please see updates on a question

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas  maybe you can also look at this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948848/how-to-pass-parameter-value-from-get-metadata-to-set-variable-in-azure-data-fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your scenario and it's working fine for me.

These are my folders and for simple demo, I took same filename `mycsv2.csv` in these two folders.

[image]

I will insert data from these 2 CSVs to a single SQL table with the additional columns as follows.

After giving Get meta data child items to ForEach, inside ForEach, use the below expression to get date part (with `/`) from the `@item().name`.

```
@replace(split(item().name,' ')[1],'.','/')
```

[image]

And give additional columns same.

[image]

the `Datepart` will give the result like this in each iteration.

[image]

**Result data in SQL table:**

[image]

Also, as you inserting data from each file into SQL table in each iteration, make sure you enable Sequential check in the ForEach.

**This is my pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcefiles",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "subfolders_getmetadata",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "foldername": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "split and replace with slash",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "Datepart",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(split(item().name,' ')[1],'.','/')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "split and replace with slash",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "additionalColumns": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "ItemName",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@item().name",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "FileDatevariable",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@variables('Datepart')",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "csvfile",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "foldername": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tablename": {
                                            "value": "@split(item().name,' ')[0]",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "Datepart": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you . Yours working fine. But I still don't understand why. 
The order of activity execution goes how it should be. But in my case it's not. What exactly causing it? See update on question.

Comment: I think your ForEach is executing in parallel. Go to ForEach and make sure you check on Sequential check box. This executes the iterations in a sequential manner, and it will give desired results as mine.

Comment: Learned something new. Thank you