# How to pass parameter value from Get Metadata to Set Variable in Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there are way I can carry a parameter value from Get Metadata activity to a Set Variable activity?

I have a FileDate parameter in GetMetadata activity. The expression for FileDate is basically stripping the date part from ForEach activity.

[image]

So how can I write an expression in Set Variable activity to reference FileDate value?
I tried something like
`@activity('GetMetadata2').output.parameters.FileDate`
but it gives an error, saying it does not have that property.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify why you want to pass parameter from Get Metadata activity to Set Variable activity?
Why cant you directly use the expression that you have used within Get Metadata activity :

```
@split(item().Name,'')[2]
```

In case if there is a concern on duplicating the logic again, you can use set variable activity initially to set the value and use that variable across all other references.